# Merge multiple versions of a modified string in JS

Tags: javascript, string, merge

Given three strings :

- `str0` is the initial text
- `str1` is a modified version of that text
- `str2` is an other modified version of that text

How to produce a string that combines modifications introduced by both versions?

For example:

```
str0 = "This is quite a short text";
str1 = "This is quite a text";
str2 = "This is QUITE a short text";
merge(str0, [str1, str2])

// should return "This is QUITE a text"
```

I am currently using [jsdiff](https://github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff) library to compare the source string `str0` with the target strings `str1` and `str2`. The function I am using (`Diff.diffWords`) returns a list of changes to be applied to `str0` in order to obtain `str1` or `str2` (words to keep, to add, to remove).

In the example, `Diff.diffWords(str0, str1)` returns

```
[
   { value: "This is quite a " },
   { removed: true, value: "short" },
   { value: "text" }
]
```

And `Diff.diffWords(str0, str2)` returns

```
[
   { value: "This is " },
   { removed: true, value: "quite" },
   { added: true, value: "QUITE" },
   { value: " a short text" }
]
```

But I not sure how to properly merge these two lists of changes in order to build the final string. Is there a known algorithm to implement in that case?

Comment: Your logic *"// should return "This is QUITE a text""* is a bit counter-intuitive.  You're removing from one but keeping uppercase.... Makes not much sense or I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: What output are you wanting in this example? You would need to diff 0 an d1, and then diff the output against 2 I'd expect.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan jsdiff library models text modification with three basic operations: words that are kept as they are, words that are removed from the initial string, and words that are added to it. (I don't know if it is a common model in diff algorithms though.)
So, in my example, `str1` removes a word ("short") and `str2` removes another word ("quite") and adds a word ("QUITE"). I hence would like to apply all these operations to `str0`. Does it make more sense?

Comment: @Matt The expected output is described in the example (see comments: `// should return "This is QUITE a text"`). Basically, I want to take into account the modifications introduced by both versions (see answer to @RokoC.Buljan above). If I diff the output of the first diff against `str2`, it will cancel the previous modifications (in the example: it will add again the word "short" that have been previously removed by `str1`).